# Deciphering lambdas in pandas column

Tags: pandas

Hello python/pandas community.
I copied this code from kaggle.com after hours of trying to turn the 'world_rank' column into a float. The code worked like magic, but I can't understand it.

Can you please explain the lambda line of code to me.

```
# convert university world rank columns to float (where necessary)
f = lambda x: int((int(x.split('-')[0]) + int(x.split('-')[1])) / 2) if len(str(x).strip()) > 3 else 
df_ranks['world_rank'] = df_ranks['world_rank'].str.replace('=','').map(
    f).astype('float')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there is no code after else?

The single line lambda code basically says this:

```
#for every element in series df['world_rank']
def foo(x):
    #if x actually contains 4 or more character(except whitespaces in front and end), i.e len > 3
    if len(str(x).strip()) > 3:
        #then do this with that element 'x' and return
        return int((int(x.split('-')[0]) + int(x.split('-')[1])) / 2)
    #else if len < 4
    else:
        #do something else
        return
```

Here, I am assuming you are aware of basic string and list indexing operations.

Comment: Thank you Gupta. With your explanation I understand almost everything I didn't understand before. 
One last thing I don't understand. At the very end, it says: str.replace('=','').map(f).

Comment: Does that mean that it is applying the function 'f' to the world_rank column?

Comment: .str.replace("=","") is a string operation applied to each element of the Series df_ranks['world_rank']. It is similar to doing a_string_variable.replace("=",""), but this only works on a single string, not on a series of string. So, you add ".str" to make it work on every string element that a pandas Series has. ".map(f)" means applying that function "f" to every element of the Series obtained after performing "replace" operation on each element of original df_rank['world_rank'] Series. Hope that helps. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm avoiding the breakdown of every element because I actually think this is poor code.

The gist of what the code is doing is splitting strings that look like `40-50` and returning the average of `40` and `50`.  It takes care of numbers like `40` by itself as well. I'll give two variations of how I'd do it.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(world_rank=['20-30', 40, '50', '60-63']))

df

  world_rank
0      20-30
1         40
2         50
3      60-63
```

## `pandas.Series.str`

```
df.assign(
    world_rank=pd.DataFrame(
        df.world_rank.astype(str).str.strip().str.split('-').tolist()
    ).astype(float).mean(1).astype(int)
)

   world_rank
0          25
1          40
2          50
3          61
```

## `numpy`

```
v = df.world_rank.values.astype(str)
a = np.core.defchararray.split(v, '-').tolist()
df.assign(world_rank=pd.DataFrame(a).astype(float).mean(1).astype(int))

   world_rank
0          25
1          40
2          50
3          61
```

Comment: Thank you for your help piRSquared, nice shirt :) I'm going to try your code on my computer at home, breaking it down piece by piece to see if I can better understand how it works. It definitely looks less convoluted and easier to read. And I see two new elements I didn't know about before in your code. Thanks for teaching me.